# why TLS symmetric encryption for same data is different in consecutive packets?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, tls1.2

I'm using wireshark to capture TLS traffic. The cipher suite which is chosen in TLS negotiation is "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)". When I send the same data in different TLS packets, the encrypted packets are not the same (Even decrypted TLS versions in wireshark are the same). Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard feature of secure encryption systems. In the case of GCM, it's because each packet is mixed with a different nonce. (A nonce is a unique value chosen for each packet, specifically to make sure that the same plaintext doesn't encrypt the same way twice.) Other secure systems achieve this by slightly different means (an initialization vector rather than a nonce, for instance), but it's a critical feature of most secure systems.

Without this feature, I could encrypt various data myself, record the encryption, and then determine when you send the same data. Or I could tell if you sent the same data more than once. A crypto system that allows that would be broken.

Comment: Dear Rob, Thanks for your nice explanation. That's so reasonable and wise.